# How to round date to closest month?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to round dates to the closest month start. For example, I would like 2022-08-30 and 2022-09-03 to both evaluate to 2022-09-01.

How can I do this with Snowflake SQL?

Answer (score 1):

We can encapsulate this logic into a SQL UDF:

```sql
create or replace function round_to_month(d date)
returns date
as $$
select x 
from (
    select date_trunc(month, d) before
        , dateadd(month, 1, before) after      
        , iff(d-before < after-d, before, after) x
)
$$
```

Sample:

```sql
with data(d) as (
    select $1::date
    from values('2020-01-10'), ('2020-01-20'), ('2020-01-16'), ('2020-01-17')
)

select *, round_to_month(d)
from data
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1: Adding 1 month to beginning of month if day of date is greater than midpoint:

```
WITH cte(d) AS (
    SELECT s.d::DATE
    FROM VALUES('2020-01-10'), ('2020-01-20'), ('2020-01-16'), 
               ('2020-01-17'), ('2022-02-14') AS s(d)
)
SELECT d
      ,DATEADD('MONTH'
               ,(DAY(d) > CEIL(DAY(LAST_DAY(d)))/2)::INT
               ,DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', d)
              ) AS round_to_month
FROM cte;
```

Output:

| D | ROUND_TO_MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-20 | 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-01-16 | 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-01-17 | 2020-02-01 |
| 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-01 |

---

Approach 2:

Snowflake provides [TIME_SLICE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_slice.html) function which is the easiest way to get start of current/next month:

```
SELECT '2022-10-13'::DATE AS d
      ,TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'START') AS prev
      ,TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'END') AS next
```

Output:

| D | PREV | NEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-13 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-11-01 |

Using the same idea as [Felipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050212/how-to-round-date-to-closest-month/74050213#74050213):

```
WITH cte(d) AS (
    SELECT s.d::DATE
    FROM VALUES('2020-01-10'), ('2020-01-20'), ('2020-01-16'),
               ('2020-01-17'), ('2022-02-14') AS s(d)
)
SELECT d,
  CASE WHEN d-TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'START') < TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'END')-d
       THEN TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'START')
       ELSE TIME_SLICE(d, 1, 'MONTH', 'END')
  END AS rount_to_month
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for `time_slice`! I should get that one in my toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using @Lukasz's sample data--We can subtract 15 days from the date to make it switch to previous month if the resulting date ends up being <=15th. We then add 1 day to the resulting `last_day()` to get to the nearest start of the month.

As @Felipe eluded in the comment, when Feb has 28 days, 15th of the month is closer to March 01 than Feb 01. To account for that, we can conditionally subtract 14 days instead.

```
select d, 
       last_day(d-15)+1, -- if we assume 15th to be the midpoint for all months
       last_day(d-iff(day(last_day(d))=28,14,15))+1 -- if we want to adjust for Feb 28
from cte;
```

Comment: Nice, `last_day(d-15)` is fun. I wish there was an easier way to adjust to Feb 28 days

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a simpler approach on this one, something like:

```sql
SELECT d, CASE
  WHEN DAY(d) >= 15 THEN DATEADD('MONTH',1,DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',d))
  ELSE DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',d)
END
```

Basically extracting your date's month if the day is lower than the 15th, or adding a month to your date month, if it is larger than the 15th.